# One or multiple database users for SQLServer access

Tags: .net, sql-server, client-server

I have developed a "CRM-like" .Net software that accesses Microsoft SQLServer Express for data storage from multiple clients. The amount of data is low (think up to 8 people in a network, sporadically making 5 to 10 entries over the course of a day).
Up until now - without giving it much thought - I have always created a single user with a singe login (and corresponding password) to login from any client. This seemed to work fine, also for concurrent access.

Now an issue has cropped up, where for one client after **one restart** of her computer, the software seems to have lost saved data - let's call them "entries" - from the **last session**, just for them to "magically appear again" after the **next restart**. Weirdly enough, my software saves entry-for-entry in single transactions and there were no Errors logged on my end. All entries had disappeared from the client software - i.e. could not be read/were not in the database at the time of the first restart - and all of them reappeared again upon the next restart - ie. were in the database and could be read.
One thing the user reported is, that she acidentally had shutdown her machine (the one with incidentally hosts the server), while another client was still connected. That client reported no lost entries.

Sorry for the lack of detail and low-fi technical description of the issue but i don't have access to the log files from the Express Server right now - if there are any - and am by no way very SQLServer-savvy.

But my question for now is: could this be in any way connected to the fact that the two clients seperately and independently connect via the same user and login? 
Is is better to have separate users (logins?) per client? Is it even wrong not to? Or can this not be the cause of any problems (then I won't go through the trouble of creating separate users).

Comment: I do not see how this is connected to the users using the same connection credentials.

Have you tried to replicate this issue? 

Are you certain the data is not in the database? It seems strange that an entry is missing and then magically reappears.

Comment: It is in the database now! I'm talking about **three** separate sessions. To go out on a limb here with my explanation: It looks to me like the "journal" from the **first session** was somehow not comitted yet (which is weird because i enclose single save operations in separate transactions) and was instead comitted together with the most recent changes from the **second session** and thus only showed up in the **third session** were all changes from session one and two where "visible", meaning they were sucessfully loaded from the database at start of the (third) session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are running the Application on a server you don't need to connect with multiple logins. There is only one Login and that's for the Application. The Application is responsible for the data access. And if you could show us the Code for saving the data it would be much easier to solve the problem. Are you using SQL commands to save the data or EntityFramework?

Note: After committing a transaction on database it will never remove from database. So check your Code. It may not Commit to database at all.

Comment: This is kind of the answer I'm looking for at the moment. I will check my code. I'm using System.Data.SQL and building SQL-Commands myself with String Resources. I try to have all my commands and connections in using-blocks which is why I don't get how a transaction could not commit, but of course there could easily be an oversight. But this is stuff for another question.

Answer (score 1):

How are you connecting to SQL? Some ORM's, such as nHibernate, can show the transaction to the current user and not to other users until it is committed.

there is no reason to use separate connections for such a small number of users. This sounds like a code issue, not a connection issue.